# wordpress plugin admin ajax - print errors for internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress

i am making ajax calls in my plugin using admin-ajax . So, when there is error, i am getting error "Internal server error" without showing the error . I cant see the logs as i dont have access to the server ? I tried like this :

```
 try{

     $req = new WP_Http;
    //$headers = array('Transfer-Encoding'=> 'chunked');  

    $res = $req->request("url", array('method' => "POST", 'body' => $data) );
  //Getting error at this line when size of $daya is more than 10MB. Till 10MB, it is sending post data successfully.
    //After 10MB(approx), getting Internal server error.
     //But cant just think this is server restriction to max post data, as phpinfo saying that max_post_size as 64MB
 }
  catch(Exception $e){
       echo $e;
   }
```

but it still returning error without returning the result . I know the line at which the error is being occured, but want to know what the error is .

Comment: Can you try setting `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your wp-config.php? That usually displays the fatal errors.

Comment: Can I edit using wordpress dashboard ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... You can try adding `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your functions.php and see if that works.

Comment: What is your memory limit? Maybe that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Just checked - Memory Limit : 128M ,

Comment: Hmmm... It's not that either :/ I don't know - unless you get to the error logs, or are able to see what the actual error is - I have no more ideas :(

Comment: wow - ini_set('memory_limit', 'bigger value'); solved the issue ! . Please write above in answer so i mark it as answer and will vote for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with big amounts of data, you need to check the memory limit - PHP usually needs more memory than the size of the data that you work with.

So try increasing the memory limit(if it doesn't work with that value, try with larger than this):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Alternatively you can let WordPress do that for you, by adding the following line to [wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP):

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Answer (score -1):

A 500 (internal server error) is an HTTP error, not a PHP one.

Generally, it is caused by a server misconfiguration (like a bad .htaccess, or a "syntax" error in httpd.conf).

Comment: Actually that's not always true. If PHP suppresses errors and you your code triggers a fatal error, you get an internal server error. I've seen this happen on many servers, including the Apache that I run on my computer. I have to change the `WP_DEBUG` setting to true in order to see the information about the error that triggered that.